# How can I read the contents of a file into a list in Lisp?

Tags: list, file-io, lisp, common-lisp

I want to read in the contents of a file into a list. Some of my attempts so far have been -

```
(defun get-file (filename)
  (let ((x (open filename)))
    (when x
      (loop for line = (read-line x nil)
     while line do (list line)))
    (close x)))

(defun get-file (filename)
  (let ((x (open filename :if-does-not-exist nil)) (contents (list nil)))
    (when x
      (loop for line = (read-line x nil)
     while line do (cons contents line)))
    (close x) contents))

(defun get-file (filename)
  (let ((x (open filename :if-does-not-exist nil)) (contents nil))
    (when x
      (loop for line = (read-line x nil)
     while line do (append contents line)))
    (close x) contents))
```

None of these worked. Can anyone tell me a way? Or even better - how to put all of the contents into an array?

Answer (score 31):

I'll add libraries in.

**edit** even easier, with `uiop`, which is included in ASDF:

```
(uiop:read-file-lines "file.txt")
```

https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/uiop.html#UIOP_002fSTREAM

also has

```
(uiop:read-file-string "file")
```

---

With [Alexandria's `read-file-into-string`](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html#IO) and split-sequence:

```
(alexandria:read-file-into-string "file.txt")
(split-sequence:split-sequence #\Newline *)
```

With [str](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str):

```
(str:lines (str:from-file "file.txt"))
```

---

More recipes on files: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/files.html

Comment: This should become the accepted answer. Every time I need to do file loading, I end up writing my own utility function. Now I've learned that my compiler has two(one for a list, one for a single string). Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

How about

```
(defun get-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
          while line
          collect line)))
```

Comment: (with-open-file (f filename)   Why do you have an f before filename there? what does collecting line do? And how does that collaborate with while line at the end?

Comment: `with-open-file` opens the file called `filename` and associates the stream with `f`. `collecting` collects the various values of `line` in a list, until the `while` is `nil`. The Common Lisp HyperSpec and Practical Common Lisp are your friends!

Comment: In other words, `with-open-file` does all the work of `open` and `close` and the `let`.

Comment: stream is a better name than f. Also it useful to move the WHILE in front of COLLECT.

Answer (score 18):

Where are the problems?

```
(defun get-file (filename)
  (let ((x (open filename)))
    (when x
      (loop for line = (read-line x nil)
            while line
            do (list line)))    ; <-- you are not collecting, just doing
    (close x)))                 ; <- the function returns the value of CLOSE

(defun get-file (filename)
  (let ((x (open filename :if-does-not-exist nil))
        (contents (list nil)))
    (when x
      (loop for line = (read-line x nil)
            while line
            do (cons contents line)))  ; <-- again, the cons goes nowhere
    (close x) contents))               ; <-- CONTENTS has never been changed

(defun get-file (filename)
  (let ((x (open filename :if-does-not-exist nil))
        (contents nil))
    (when x
      (loop for line = (read-line x nil)
            while line
            do (append contents line)))  ; <- again the result goes nowhere
    (close x) contents))                 ; <-- CONTENTS has never been changed
```

**LOOP**

The `DO` clause of `LOOP` will just execute something for side effects.

`COLLECT` will collect the result and the `LOOP` then will return a list of collected values upon exit.

**Opening and closing of files**

As already mentioned, use `WITH-OPEN-FILE` instead of `OPEN`/`CLOSE`. `WITH-OPEN-FILE` will close the file upon leaving the dynamic scope. Not just from a normal exit, but also upon error conditions, by using `UNWIND-PROTECT` to ensure the execution.

**Reading file contents**

If you want to read the contents of a file, you can use the function `READ-SEQUENCE`. With the usual problems. For example when you read an ASCII file as text into a string, the string may be shorter than the file. For example Common Lisp will represent internally CRLF with a single character, on platforms where CRLF is newline. Another example: in Unicode supporting implementations the UTF-8 code in the file may be replaced with a single character.

Answer (score 0):

**2023 Update**

With the [Transducer](https://github.com/fosskers/cl-transducers) pattern it's very easy to process the contents of a file (or any other stream of data). For a file specifically:

```lisp
(t:transduce #'t:pass #'t:cons #p"path/to/file.txt")
```

This will read each line from the given file into a list. Note that there's not much reason to do this, as any processing you'd likely want to do on the list after that can be accomplished *during* the transduction itself, thus avoiding the need to pull the entire file into memory at once.

For instance, to count the number of words in a file:

```lisp
(t:transduce (t:comp (t:map #'str:words) ;; (2) Split each line into a list of words.
                     #'t:concatenate)    ;; (3) Flatten that list back into a single stream.
             #'t:count       ;; (4) Count the total number of split words.
             #p"foobar.txt") ;; (1) Read from a file, one line at a time.
```

Note that the `t:` namespace prefix in either example is the nickname assumed to have been given to the library upon import, as in:

```lisp
(:local-nicknames (#:t #:transducers))
```