# Lisp code to read csv file into a list of lists.

Tags: csv, lisp, common-lisp

I have this code from Python to read a csv (comma separated text values) file line by line as string and then split each such line string into fields and print each on console:

```
def readfilefn(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
        for line in f:
            flds = line.split(',')  
            for fld in flds:
                print fld.strip()
```

I am trying to convert this to Lisp code. I found following code on [How can I read the contents of a file into a list in Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813895/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-a-file-into-a-list-in-lisp) :

```
(defun get-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
          while line
          collect line)))
```

and one from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/r8O6Py8E1zE

```
(defun read-all-lines (input-stream)
  (do ((line nil)
       (result nil (cons line result)))
      ((eq line :eof) (nreverse result))
   (setq line (read-line input-stream nil :eof))))
```

(here the lines will have to be reversed using nreverse).

For splitting of full line string into field strings: https://gist.github.com/siguremon/1174988

```
(defun split-str (string &optional (separator " "))
  (split-str-1 string separator))

(defun split-str-1 (string &optional (separator " ") (r nil))
  (let ((n (position separator string
             :from-end t
             :test #'(lambda (x y)
                   (find y x :test #'string=)))))
    (if n
    (split-str-1 (subseq string 0 n) separator (cons (subseq string (1+ n)) r))
      (cons string r))))
```

There are many other routines also available everywhere, e.g. http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/visual-lisp-autolisp-and-general/need-a-lisp-routine-to-string-split/td-p/2618387

I want to know if these are safe approaches or which would be the best approach. I am using clisp (Common Lisp) on Linux. Thanks for your comments/answers.

Comment: The easiest option would be to use an existing library. [cl-csv](https://github.com/AccelerationNet/cl-csv) seems to have a function to read a file into a list of lists.

Comment: You are trying to convert the Python code? What do you have so far?

Comment: I am not able to something as simple as Python code.

Comment: Take a look at CL-PPRE and "split": http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/#split

Comment: Note that your original version is will fail on corner cases allowed by  [RFC4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).

Comment: By original do you mean the python code?

Comment: I usually use the library `fare-csv`, which in my experience had the fewest problems with corner cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry for being a bit late, as suggested in a comment by jkilky, I will use the common lisp library cl-csv, it is available via quicklisp.

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :cl-csv)
To load "cl-csv":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-csv
; Loading "cl-csv"
...
(:CL-CSV)
```

The cl-csv split your file in a list of lists let's use the csv file from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/train.csv) called train.csv is a normal csv file:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
8,0,3,"Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard",male,2,3,1,349909,21.075,,S
9,1,3,"Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)",female,27,0,2,347742,11.1333,,S
10,1,2,"Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)",female,14,1,0,237736,30.0708,,C
11,1,3,"Sandstrom, Miss. Marguerite Rut",female,4,1,1,PP 9549,16.7,G6,S
12,1,1,"Bonnell, Miss. Elizabeth",female,58,0,0,113783,26.55,C103,S
13,0,3,"Saundercock, Mr. William Henry",male,20,0,0,A/5. 2151,8.05,,S
...
...
```

The Cl-csv loads it in a list of lists each row is a list:

```
CL-USER> (cl-csv:read-csv #P"./train.csv")
(("PassengerId" "Survived" "Pclass" "Name" "Sex" "Age" "SibSp" "Parch" "Ticket"
  "Fare" "Cabin" "Embarked")
 ("1" "0" "3" "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris" "male" "22" "1" "0" "A/5 21171" "7.25"
  "" "S")
 ("2" "1" "1" "Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)" "female"
  "38" "1" "0" "PC 17599" "71.2833" "C85" "C")
 ("3" "1" "3" "Heikkinen, Miss. Laina" "female" "26" "0" "0" "STON/O2. 3101282"
  "7.925" "" "S")
 ("4" "1" "1" "Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)" "female" "35" "1"
  "0" "113803" "53.1" "C123" "S")
 ("5" "0" "3" "Allen, Mr. William Henry" "male" "35" "0" "0" "373450" "8.05" ""
  "S")
 ("6" "0" "3" "Moran, Mr. James" "male" "" "0" "0" "330877" "8.4583" "" "Q")
 ("7" "0" "1" "McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J" "male" "54" "0" "0" "17463" "51.8625"
  "E46" "S")
 ("8" "0" "3" "Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard" "male" "2" "3" "1" "349909"
  "21.075" "" "S")
```

Then to print it up just use the format function, this is a little trick for printing lists and a separator for each list, I use nil instead of t for getting a string, but you could print it with t, so this is the one-liner to get this in lisp, I used the new line separator for the first level of lists (then rows) and then a ", " for the items of the rows:

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~{~{~a,  ~}~% ~}" (cl-csv:read-csv #P"train.csv"))

"PassengerId,  Survived,  Pclass,  Name,  Sex,  Age,  SibSp,  Parch,  Ticket,  Fare,  Cabin,  Embarked,  
 1,  0,  3,  Braund, Mr. Owen Harris,  male,  22,  1,  0,  A/5 21171,  7.25,  ,  S,  
 2,  1,  1,  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer),  female,  38,  1,  0,  PC 17599,  71.2833,  C85,  C,  
 3,  1,  3,  Heikkinen, Miss. Laina,  female,  26,  0,  0,  STON/O2. 3101282,  7.925,  ,  S,  
 4,  1,  1,  Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel),  female,  35,  1,  0,  113803,  53.1,  C123,  S,  
 5,  0,  3,  Allen, Mr. William Henry,  male,  35,  0,  0,  373450,  8.05,  ,  S,  
 6,  0,  3,  Moran, Mr. James,  male,  ,  0,  0,  330877,  8.4583,  ,  Q,  
 7,  0,  1,  McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J,  male,  54,  0,  0,  17463,  51.8625,  E46,  S,  
 8,  0,  3,  Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard,  male,  2,  3,  1,  349909,  21.075,  ,  S,  
 9,  1,  3,  Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg),  female,  27,  0,  2,  347742,  11.1333,  ,  S,  
 10,  1,  2,  Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem),  female,  14,  1,  0,  237736,  30.0708,  ,  C,  
 11,  1,  3,  Sandstrom, Miss. Marguerite Rut,  female,  4,  1,  1,  PP 9549,  16.7,  G6,  S,  
 12,  1,  1,  Bonnell, Miss. Elizabeth,  female,  58,  0,  0,  113783,  26.55,  C103,  S,  
 13,  0,  3,  Saundercock, Mr. William Henry,  male,  20,  0,  0,  A/5. 2151,  8.05,  ,  S,  
 14,  0,  3,  Andersson, Mr. Anders Johan,  male,  39,  1,  5,  347082,  31.275,  ,  S,  
 15,  0,  3,  Vestrom, Miss. Hulda Amanda Adolfina,  female,  14,  0,  0,  350406,  7.8542,  ,  S,  
 16,  1,  2,  Hewlett, Mrs. (Mary D Kingcome) ,  female,  55,  0,  0,  248706,  16,  ,  S,  
 17,  0,  3,  Rice, Master. Eugene,  male,  2,  4,  1,  382652,  29.125,  ,  Q,  
 18,  1,  2,  Williams, Mr. Charles Eugene,  male,  ,  0,  0,  244373,  13,  ,  S,  
 19,  0,  3,  Vander Planke, Mrs. Julius (Emelia Maria Vandemoortele),  female,  31,  1,  0,  345763,  18,  ,  S,
```

I hope that this helps

Comment: Thanks for a well illustrated answer.

Comment: I am actually now using Racket, which is a Scheme/Lisp derivative. Would you equivalent package for Racket?

Comment: Well, I do not know Racket but it have package managers as quicklisp, and two catalogs for example here https://pkgs.racket-lang.org/#, youa have csv and csv-reading

Comment: Thanks. I will try these.

Comment: Excellent presentation.  Thank you much.  Just what I needed.

Comment: Hi, great it help, @TheGeeko61 considerer upvoting if it really helped you