# Confused about Common LISP `loop for var =` syntax

Tags: loops, common-lisp

I checked the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813895/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-a-file-into-a-list-in-lisp) on how to loop over a file. I checked several places online trying to understand what is going on in that code snipped posted here again:

```
(defun get-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
          while line
          collect line)))
```

This syntax seems to be so arcane, and the references are not trivial to understand. According to the reference [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node244.html) " the fourth of seven for/as syntaxes", the syntax is:

for *var* [type-spec] = *expr1* [then *expr2*]

And if there is no *expr2*, then *expr1* is used.

**What is confusing me:**

I am lost at the lines without knowing what to ask other than how does it work:

```
      while line
      collect line
```

I wouldn't know how to substitute that with other code. It does not look like a list at all. My intuition would tell me that it should've looked something like:

```
(while line (collect line))
```

Also, isn't that also same as:

```
while line collect line
```

And what is the *expr1*:

```
(read-line stream nil)
              while line
              collect line)
```

or

```
      while line
      collect line
```

What if I had much more code instead of `collect line`? Will there be no lists? I don't see the structure.

I know these are more than 1 question, but probably there is something big I am missing, preventing me from asking a good question.

Comment: The extended `LOOP` macro defines its own domain specific language for writing loops, so the syntax is different from regular Common Lisp. Try reading the [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/), particularly chapter [22. LOOP for Black Belts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html).

Comment: I looked that up already. It doesn't elaborate on the form in this post.

Comment: Did you read the whole chapter? Sections "Equals-Then Iteration",  "Termination Tests" and "Value Accumulation" should explain `FOR ... = ...`, `WHILE` and `COLLECT` respectively.

Comment: `:collect line :and :do expression ...`. The loop is its own language and very non lispy syntax. It is very complex to learn all of it so moody people knows a subset. It's unique to CL so similar code in other lisps look very different.

Comment: Yes I read it. I am not interested in collect at all, and I find it lacking in explaining some theory for good reasons. It is "Practical" after all. Please see the comments in Rainer's answer. We are getting somewhere

Comment: To get a list of lines in two lines, I added an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48185783/1506338

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a loop. Stuff which runs multiple times.

Basically the loop has two parts:

1. part one defines a variable `line` and what happens to it: on each loop iteration `line` is set to the result of evaluating the expression `(read-line stream nil)`. This means that lines get read one by one.
2. the second part are the clauses which are run on each iteration. This part says: as long as the variable `line` is not `nil` collect the value of `line` into a list.

Thus each line is read and as long there is a line, collect it into a list. If the end of the input stream (which is a file stream) is reached, the `(read-line stream nil)` form returns `nil`, the `while` sees that `line` is `nil`. `nil` is false and thus the loop is terminated. Then the so far collected lines will be returned as the result.

The whole `loop` form returns the collected list of lines.

Here `loop` is convenient because:

- it conditionally collects a value
- we don't need to give the result list a variable name, because there is only one accumulation going on: the single `collect ...` clause.
- the result list is returned in the correct order: first collected item is the first element in the returned list

**Background**

Generally `LOOP` is a macro, which is based on the similar `FOR` macro from Interlisp of the early 70s. There the idea was introduced to have program constructs which could be used like normal english: *for item in list collect item*. This was called *conversational Lisp*. Similar ideas are for example used in Applescript, a simple scripting language from Apple. This style was never very popular in Lisp (though there are other macros using it), but the `loop` macro remained, because it turned out to be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the background information. I understand now that collect and while are specific to loop. Why can't I do something like: while line (format t "found a line") for example. I am not seeing how to operate on the read lines.

Comment: @Makketronix if you don't want to `collect` something, you can `do` something:  `while line do (print "found a line")`

Comment: Aha. So why doesn't (format t "found a line") work? That, with the use of collect, confused the hell out of me.

Comment: @Makketronix: it does work. As I said you need to write `do` in front of it. Clauses are introduced by words like while, until, when, unless, collect, sum, do, maximize, and others...

Comment: It does indeed, after I restarted the environment... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> My intuition would tell me that it should've looked something like:
>
> (while line (collect line))

So you might like Shinmera's FOR macro: https://github.com/Shinmera/for

The minimum one need to know is `for… over`, where over is generic, it works with many data types.

```
(for:for ((a over '(1 2 3))
          (b over #(a b c))
          (c over (for:for ((table as (make-hash-table))) 
                    (setf (gethash (random 10) table) (random 10)) (repeat 3)))
          (d over *package*)
          (e over *random-state*)
          (f over (directory (merge-pathnames "*.*" (user-homedir-pathname))))
          (g over (make-string-input-stream "Hi!")))
  (print (list a b c d e f g)))
```

Comment: This is why I am liking Lisp more and more, not necessarily what is "lisped".