# LISP iterative to recursive

Tags: recursion, iteration, lisp, common-lisp

I wrote down this iterative code in LISP using the loop function:

```
(defun loadfile (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil 'eof)
          until (eq line 'eof)
          collect line)))
    )
  )
```

Is there a way to rewrite it without `loop`, in a recursive way?

Comment: Yes, but does it look like a task that requires a recursive approach?

Comment: yes, i did using loop but the task (unfortunately) clearly says _"don't use LOOP, DO, DOLIST, DOTIMES"_

Comment: I see; note that apparently there is no restriction about `tagbody` ;-)

Comment: Ah allright this is homework right ? To do this in two lines in real life, I suggest this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813895/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-a-file-into-a-list-in-lisp/48185783#48185783

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course any loop can be transformed in recursion, but reading an entire file a line at time, is, however, a typical iterative process, so I find this question difficult to motivate.

Here is a possible recursive version, where the recursion is managed by an internal function:

```
(defun load-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (labels ((read-recursively ()
               (let ((line (read-line stream nil 'eof)))
                 (if (eq line 'eof)
                     nil
                     (cons line (read-recursively))))))
      (read-recursively))))
```

This solution is prone to a stack-overflow error if the number of rows of the file is big.

If one has a compiler which can perform tail optimization, the following alternative recursive solution *could* be compiled in iterative fashion and *could* avoid the stack-overflow:

```
(defun load-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (labels ((read-recursively (read-so-far)
               (let ((line (read-line stream nil 'eof)))
                 (if (eq line 'eof)
                     (reverse read-so-far)
                     (read-recursively (cons line read-so-far))))))
      (read-recursively ()))))
```

Comment: File has to contain just one row (probably a long one), so i think that each one of the two solutions can be used, am i correct?

Comment: @DouglasP Only one row? then why loop, just call `read-line` once

Comment: Yes but i want to try something in case i have more rows. thank you

Answer (score 6):

Surprise them with a GOTO instead:

```
(defun loadfile (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (prog (line lines)
      repeat
      (setf line (read-line stream nil))
      (when line
        (push line lines)
        (go repeat))
      (return (reverse lines)))))
```