# Why is there an = sign in loop macros for reading lines out of a file?

Tags: loops, syntax, common-lisp

I have become stuck trying to figure out how to handle reading files in common-lisp because the answers are always seemingly the exact same and I don't understand lisp's loop macro syntax or something about it. 
In the code below (from [this stackexchange answer for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813895/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-a-file-into-a-list-in-lisp) you see that there is a "loop for line = (read-line )..." I don't understand what the numeric = sign means in terms of the test. Why is it the numeric equal sign? what number does read-line return? Are nil and T numbers?

```
(defun get-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
          while line
          collect line)))
```

I always intuitively think that "(loop for line in (read-line )..." is going to work because read-line returns a string, but I **guess** it actually returns the value of nil, and the string is just some junk it puts on the terminal...but I don't get that. 
Anybody have insights? or a method to this madness?

Comment: The `loop` macro is a DSL for iteration. Its syntax is often considered un-lispy but I got used to it. The `=` has nothing to do with numerical values but is just an assignment operator which binds the return value of `read-line` to `line`. I guess it is just a matter of getting used to it or try a plain `do' loop.

Comment: Besides of Rainer's Answer you can find a good introduction [here](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html)

Comment: @MartinBuchmann Your first comment is actually the only correct answer to my question on the page. It clears the fundamental misunderstanding. The = keyword in loop has different _semantics_ than the = function in Common Lisp. I misunderstood by assuming they were the same (or similar).I wish I could mark a comment as the answer! (I came back to this question because it still isn't marked answered)

Answer (score 3):

**(**

start a Lisp form

**loop**

this is the `LOOP` macro

**for line = (read-line stream nil)**

we define a local variable `line` and on each `loop` iteration it will be set to the result of `(read-line stream nil)`.

`(read-line stream nil)` returns a line as a string or `nil` if stream is at eof.

**while line**

check this on each iteration and keep iterating while the variable `line` is not `nil`

If it is `nil` then exit from `loop` and return a result.

**collect line**

for each iteration collect the content of the variable `line` into a list, which can then later returned as a result.

**)**

end of the Lisp form

Answer (score 3):

The loop macro is unique in Common Lisp, i.e. it's the only macro that defines it's own - ah - entire little grammar.  This grammar is more like something you'd encounter in an Algol, Pascal, C, or Python language specification.  The loop macro parses this and converts it into more standard Lisp form.

The body of a `loop` is thus a series of statement.  In your example there are three beginning respectively with `for`, `with` and `collect`.

All this is a source of confusion for beginners.

For example you see that the token =, and you go look that up in the manual.  You find a function for testing numeric equality.  But inside of the loop macro, inside of the `for` statement, it part of the little grammar the loop macro is using

That FOR clause is going to arrange to bind a lexical variable `line` to the result for calling `(read-line stream nil)` each time around the loop.

Another source of confusion here is that the `READ-LINE` function take a stream along with a few optional parameters.  Here only one is provided, i.e. nil.  That argument controls what happens when `read-line` gets to the end of the file.  `Nil` suppresses the error it would natural raise, and instead asks it to return the value NIL.

That may seem a bit odd because while most of the time read-line returns a `string` this optional parameter has licensed it to return two types: `string` or `null`.

The `while` clause deals with that, terminating the loop when we get a value of type `null`, i.e. the nil value.

The `collect` clause is interesting because is doing a lot of work for the loop's author.  It magically creates state in the loop to accumulate the individual line into a list and then return that list when the loop exits.  Typical implementations of the loop macro will do this very efficiently.

It is a common reaction at this point in learning the language to mumble something like, "wtf?  this doesn't seem very Lisp like?!?"  And while that's fair `loop` is extremely useful and there is a lot of code out there that uses it.

There are alternatives, for example `iterate` (which isn't part of the standard) and `series` (which was a late addition).  But both are a bit odd/clever in their own ways.

Comment: SERIES was _not_ added to the standard, even though it was in CLtL2.