# How can I read all .text files in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, readfile

I want to read all text files in from a folder in Lisp? Like "foldername/*.txt" in c when I use shell script.

Comment: To help: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/files.html

Comment: To read one file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813895/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-a-file-into-a-list-in-lisp/48185783#48185783

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CL-USER 33 > (directory "/usr/share/examples/DTTk/*.txt")
(#P"/usr/share/examples/DTTk/hotspot_example.txt"
 #P"/usr/share/examples/DTTk/pridist_example.txt"
 #P"/usr/share/examples/DTTk/opensnoop_example.txt" 
 #P"/usr/share/examples/DTTk/syscallbysysc_example.txt"
 #P"/usr/share/examples/DTTk/rwbytype_example.txt"  ...)

CL-USER 34 > (mapcar (lambda (path)
                        (with-output-to-string (o)
                          (with-open-file (s path)
                            (loop for line = (read-line s nil)
                                  while line do (write-line line o)))))
                     *)
("The following is a demonstration of the hotspot.d script. ... " ...)
```