# End of file (character) in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Basically im trying to read lines from a file recursively (because i can't use any loop cycle), but i don't know where the file ends.

This is my function:

```
;; (get-problemas 0)
(defun get-problemas (indice &optional file (problemas '()))
  (cond
   ((null file) (with-open-file (open "C:/Users/nunor/Desktop/problemas.dat" :direction :input :if-does-not-exist nil)
                  (get-problemas (1+ indice) open (cons (read open) nil))
                )
   )
   (t (cond
       ((= indice 6) problemas)
       (t (get-problemas (1+ indice) file (append problemas (cons (read file) nil))))
      )
   )
  )
)
```

I'm using a counter 'indice' to stop de recursion because i dont kow how to stop when i reached the end of the file.

And i'm putting the lists that the file contains in to a list called 'problemas'.

The file looks like this:

```
(a (((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 1) (0 0 1)) ((0 0 0) (0 1 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 1))) 3) 
(b (((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 1) (0 0 1)) ((0 0 0) (0 1 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 1))) 3) 
(c (((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 1) (0 0 1)) ((0 0 0) (0 1 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 1))) 3) 
(d (((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 1) (0 0 1)) ((0 0 0) (0 1 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 1))) 3) 
(e (((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 1) (0 0 1)) ((0 0 0) (0 1 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 1))) 3) 
(f (((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 1) (0 0 1)) ((0 0 0) (0 1 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 1))) 3)
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: have you checked the READ function?

Answer (score 3):

Look at [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813895/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-a-file-into-a-list-in-lisp) that use `loop` and rewrite them into recursion. Take for example this one:

```
(defun get-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
          while line
          collect line)))
```

Note the usage of `(read-line stream nil)`, which returns `nil` at the end of the file. You can just repeatedly call it and save the result of each call until you will get `nil`:

```
(defun read-until-null (f)
  (let ((result (read-line f nil)))
    (unless (null result)
      (cons result (read-until-null f)))))

(defun file-to-lines (path)
  (with-open-file (f path :direction :input :if-does-not-exist nil)
    (read-until-null f)))
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
(defun get-problemas (&optional file (problemas nil))
  (if file
    (let ((prob (read file nil)))
      (if prob
        (get-problemas file (cons prob problemas))
        (nreverse problemas)))
    (with-open-file (stream (open "problemas.dat" :direction :input))
      (get-problemas stream))))
```

Notes:

1. We pass arguments to `read` so that it doesn't throw an error, but returns `nil`. We detect this `nil` to terminate the recursion.
2. Your tail recursion with explicit accumulator is good; I improved it by avoiding `append` and accumulating the output in reverse. When we terminate the recursion, we `nreverse` the reversed list of "problemas".
3. I got rid of the `:if-does-not-exist nil`. If the file doesn't exist, we want to bail, and not recurse.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than all the hair about the file argument it's natural to split this into two functions.  One deals with opening the file:

```
(defun get-problemas (&optional (file "C:/Users/nunor/Desktop/problemas.dat"))
  (with-open-file (in file :direction :input)
    (with-standard-io-syntax
      (let ((*read-eval* nil))
        (get-problemas/accumulate in '())))))
```

Note this uses `with-standard-io-syntax` and binds `*read-eval*` to nil which are both elementary safety precautions which far too few Lisp programmers use.

The second, recursive, function builds the list of problems.  It uses a trick which also seems to be unknown to too many Lisp programmers: to detect the end of file you return the stream itself since this is an object which can't (without great heroics) be in data read from the file:

```
(defun get-problemas/accumulate (in accumulation)
  (let ((got (read in nil in)))
    (if (eql got in)
        (reverse accumulation)
      (get-problemas/accumulate in (cons got accumulation)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem.
To know if i reached the end of the file i used "(read file nil 'eof)", if it reached the end of the file 'line' is going to be 'eof, and in cond i verify if 'line' is equal to 'eof so the recursion can stop.

This is how my function looks like now:

```
(defun get-problemas (&optional file (problemas '()))
  (cond
   ((null file) (with-open-file (open "C:/Users/nunor/Desktop/problemas.dat" :direction :input :if-does-not-exist nil)
                  (get-problemas open (cons (read open) nil))
                )
   )
   (t (let
          (
           (line (read file nil 'eof))
          )
        (cond
         ((eq line 'eof) problemas)
         (t (get-problemas file (append problemas (cons line nil))))
        )
      )
   )
  )
)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: there are still issues. The formatting with the parentheses on its own lines is strange. Recursively calling the function to read lines may cause a stack overflow. Appending to the end of a list is much slower than adding an element to the front. The variable `FILE` has not the best name, since the value of the variable is a stream and not a file.